# How do I make a font awesome icon glow with a specific color

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, blogger

How do I make individual font awesome icons glow with a specific color in my blogger blog and where exactly do I place it in the html editor

Comment: @ifconfig I suspect you mis-read the question ;)

Comment: Yes, @Clonkex you are correct. My mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with CSS classes. For example:

**HTML**

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa-address-book {
  color: #ff0000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #ff0000;
}
```

This would give a red glowing effect to that particular icon. *Make sure your own style.css is loaded **after** the fontawesome css if using this method.*

Alternatively you could create a new CSS class

```
.redGlow {
  color: #ff0000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #ff0000;
}
```

And use that class in the HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book redGlow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

If Blogger does not allow you to edit style sheets, you could add the CSS inline like so:

```
 <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true" style=“color: #ff0000; text-shadow: 0 0 3px #ff0000;”></i>
```

Comment: I tried your answers but I just didn't get it...probably I'm not putting the code right. Although the inline CSS will be better. `<a class='social-facebook' href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-facebook'/></a>` is the icon to be glowed

Comment: Try this: <a class=‘social-facebook’ href=‘#’ target=‘_blank’><i class=‘fa fa-facebook’ style=‘text-shadow: 0 0 3px #ff0000; color: #ff0000;’></i></a>

Comment: I did the CSS again and it worked but then it overrides the hover attribute

Comment: Yes!...It worked. Although had to make infinitesimal changes to the quotation marks. `<a class='social-facebook' href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-facebook' style='text-shadow: 0 0 3px #ff0000; color: #ff0000;'></i></a>` My gratitude.

Comment: But is there a way to make it not override the hover attribute while using the inline CSS

Comment: Do you have access to edit the .social-facebook class? Inline CSS will always override any other styles. Attached Stylesheets > CSS within the HTML document > inline styles. Each gets overridden by the next. If you are able to access the CSS where your hover effect is applied, a hacky way to do it would be !important for example .social-facebook:hover { color: #00ff00 !important;} if you are unable to access the original CSS try adding that little snippet between <style></style> tags near the top of your HTML code (just before the </head> tag)

Comment: A less hacky way would be to use my 2nd method from original answer with all the CSS between <style> tags as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Still overrides it using the 2nd method...but it's all good. The primary goal has been achieved.

Answer (score 2):

You can help of `box-shadow` property:

```css
.fa-pied-piper-alt {
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 3px red;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);
  margin:50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<span class="fa fa-pied-piper-alt"></span>
```